# Libgdx Project With Android Studio: No Android class can be resolved such as TextView,ImageView, SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

so I have this problem, I have created my first game with Libgdx library. Everything is working fine but when it comes to saving the score I have to use the class SharedPreferences right?but it seems the android studio can't resolve it. The thing it is not importing any android class at all. So I think it's some dependency or repository issue. It's my first project with libgdx so I don't know. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a LibGDX project is set up with separate modules. The core module does not have direct access to Android classes because the core code can also be used by desktop builds.

LibGDX has abstracted the Android SharedPreferences into an object called simply Preferences, so you can use that instead in your core module. You can access that via `Gdx.app.getPreferences()`. There's a section in the LibGDX documentation on how to use Preferences.

If you need Android classes that don't already have LibGDX counterparts, you can write an interface in your core module that has the methods you need, implement that interface in the Android module, and pass the implementation into your game's constructor. There are examples in the LibGDX documentation under "Interfacing with platform-specific code".